GCP cloud SQL double peering
We have an hub and spoke network with a local machine that needs access to a cloud SQL instance like the following
local machine --> vpn --> landing net --> peering --> shared net --> peering --> cloud SQL
due to the double peering and non transitive peering we cannot do that directly. Following this guide ,it should be possible to use GCP cloud SQL proxy but it's not clear how to connect without opening an ssh tunnel.
Any idea on how to solve the double peering routing without changing network topology

Have a look on PSC https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-private-service-connect

+1 to above comment. This is a great example of where PSC would make life easier and allow you to avoid the issue of peering transitive VPCs.

We tried with PSC but we still have problems with peering, since Private Service Connect endpoint is accessed from a peered network (https://cloud.google.com/network-intelligence-center/docs/connectivity-tests/states/reasons-dropped-packets#psc-endpoint-accessed-from-peered-network). It's best practice to attach a PSC endpoint to each subnet that needs to connect to cloud SQL instance?. We have a paloalto centralized NVA architecture with hub spoke network topology and seems adding complex https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-foundation-fabric/tree/master/fast/stages/2-networking-c-nva
